# How many circles needed to pass through each of 5x5 lattice points?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, optimization

[image]

You are given a 5x5 set of lattice points. What is the minimum number
of circles, which pass through each of the 25 points at least once?

Comment: Is the set a 5x5 rectangle of lattice points, or do we have 25 lattice points all over the place?

Comment: I added a picture to clarify!

Comment: https://oeis.org/A262355

Comment: OEIS acknowledges that doesn't seem to generalize to NxN. Also, for the same problem with circular arcs, see [A187679](https://oeis.org/A187679), which doesn't seem to have been investigated at n=7 or beyond.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a proof we can't do it with less than

> 5

circles.

Each circle covers at most 8 points. In fact, the max is 6 points except for these five 8-point circles:

```
x O x O x   x O O x x   x x x x x   x x x x x   x x O O x
O x x x O   O x x O x   x O O x x   x x O O x   x O x x O
x x x x x   O x x O x   O x x O x   x O x x O   x O x x O
O x x x O   x O O x x   O x x O x   x O x x O   x x O O x
x O x O x   x x x x x   x O O x x   x x O O x   x x x x x
```

Note that any two of the 8-point circles overlap at two points. This means that each one beyond the first covers 6 new points at best. So, the total point coverage from 4 circles is at most **8 + 6 + 6 + 6 = 26** points. That's just above 25 points in the grid, but this leave little slack, and we run into trouble covering the corners or center.

One of the five 8-point circles must be present. First, say it's the first-listed one:

```
x O x O x
O x x x O
x x x x x
O x x x O
x O x O x
```

Then, it's not possible to cover the center point while covering 4 points not already covered by that 8-point circle. This is because the only >4-point circle covering the center is below, with lowercase `o` marking redundantly covered points.

```
O o x x x
x x O x x
x x O x x
o O x x x
x x x x x
```

If it's one of the other 8-point circle, we can say it's the one below on account of symmetry.

```
x O O x x
O x x O x
O x x O x
x O O x x
x x x x x
```

Any circle that covers the top left corner gives at most 4 new points not already covered by this eight-point circle, since the only >4-point circles covering that corner are those below and reflections, with redundant points marked with lowercase `o`.

```
O o x x x   O x o x x
x x O x x   x x x o x
x x O x x   x x x x x
O o x x x   x x x O x
x x x x x   O x O x x
```

Either way we're limited to **8 + 6 + 6 + 4 = 24** points covered.

Comment: The ASCII representations here were very helpful for understanding the proof.

Comment: Though, we have a 4 point circle whose origin is the center and covers the four corners

Comment: @zixuanisbadatPuzzling That's fine, as long as there's one circle with 4 points or less, the proof goes through.

Comment: _"That's because the only type of circle covering >4 points including a corner is the 6-point circle below, but it covers only one corner, so we can't cover all four corners while still having our 8-point circle."_ Looks obviously wrong to me. (Take the large 8 point circle and move it one g.u. either horizontally or vertically.)

Comment: @PaulPanzer Good find, let me see if I can fix this.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I think this works now, with some more casework. Could you check if I missed anything?

Comment: @xnor let me fix my own one first which I see now has a similar bug.